# How far does an arrow travel underwater?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I was fighting drowns, I used both a bow and a crossbow, because I did not have any other good weapons. It seems that the crossbow shoots farther.

How far does the arrows go from each weapon? I need to know.
Also, are fireworks affected by water? Will they be good weapons against drowns (and guardians)?

Answer (score 1):

I did a test in a Creative world, and I found out that:

- Crossbows **and** bows shoot about the same distance from the player underwater
- Crossbows and bows shoot **12 blocks away from the player** underwater

As for fireworks, they seem to work the same way as they do on land. They aren't very good weapons, because they can only be used on a block, and they go pretty high. This means that you are most likely going to be able to miss your target.

Conclusion: Bows and Crossbows shoot 12 blocks, fireworks work normally, and none of these are very good weapons to use underwater.

Comment: what about fireworks on a crossbow? or is that a java only thing?

Comment: Actually, I learned not that long ago that fireworks on crosswbows exist on bedrock edition. You just have to put the fireworks on your off-hand (yea i know off-hand doesn't really work on bedrock, but trust me). I'll test this out tomorrow, and ill let you know when i update